# Fitting square root model to data in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a data set of the following:

```
% Release      time(min)

0,260833333     0
8,459266487     10
12,29324414     20
29,13909919     35
23,90141842     60
42,56069428     100
104,2425023     150
```

How can I fit this data using sum of squares to a square root model `y = sqrt(x)` , which has 100% release as a boundary (thus expecting the model 100% release to be a little below 150 min)? Very stupid question sorry, but I can't seem to figure it out on Excel. Thanks in advance to anyone who can help me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about creating a maths formula; not about creating a worksheet formula that produces the results of a maths formula. This question belongs on SE's [Mathematics site](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The square root formula you posted doesn't have a parameter to fit. Try fitting something like

y = a + b*sqrt(x)

instead. You can use the Excel solver to find the best fitting a and b.

Comment: I indeed added a parameter to the function and got it working as I wanted now by fitting to this parameter. Thanks for the comment nevertheless.